# Is a tab considered to be one character?

Tags: character, spaces

Is a tab considered to be one character?
If so does that mean that when used against spaces a tab uses less space, in memory, despite having the same length of multiple spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you right. if you used to program in c/c++/java a tab is presented by the character '\t' which is 0x09 in the ascii table. but the whitespace is presented by the number 0x20.
if you use a text editor you can. text that by the displayed count of the characters presented in the text.

knows ,that the width of tab of '\t' character can be changed in the text editor setting.

if you know ascii table and hexadecimal numbers you can dump a file containing, spaces in one line, and a tab on the second line in you like. ( use od command if you use unix based os ). otherwise, knows that in disk a tab is one think and bunch of spaces making a tab is another thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tabs are considered to be one character. one quick way of checking this is by opening any text editor and using tabs and spaces. the text editor will show the columns as one and two despite the first having a bigger length